# template inherited class derived-base assignment

Tags: c++, templates

I have 2 classes, A and B and B is derived from A. I'm not allowed to change them. I'm implementing smart pointer class.

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPtr{
    ...
    SmartPtr& operator=(const SmartPtr& p); 
    ...
}

template<typename T>
SmartPtr<T>& SmartPtr<T>::operator=(const SmartPtr & p) {
    ++*p.cnt;
    if(--*cnt == 0) { 
        delete ptr; 
        delete cnt; 
    }
    ptr = p.ptr;
    cnt = p.cnt;
    return *this;
}
```

I get error when I try to assign SmartPtr A to SmartPtr B as operand types are different. How can I fix that without changing A and B?

Comment: There are plnety of smart pointer implementations. Why do you want to implement one ?

Comment: Could you please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The interface of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is a good guideline when implementing smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

## your answer

I think you might mean `SmartPtr<A>` and `SmartPtr<B>`. Of course you won't be able to assign them, because class A is not class B.
You will need to add another assignment operator, that looks like this

```
tempalte <typename U>
SmartPtr<T>& operator=(const SmartPtr<U>& p);
```

if you like to, you could use `std::enable_if` to make sure, U is derived from T

```
template <typename U>
SmartPtr<T>& operator=(const typename SmartPtr<std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<T, U>::value, U>::type &p);
```

and then you can implement this, by using `dynamic_cast` in your code to convert A to B

## the 'correct' answer

using std::shared_ptr you could use this
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast